# Extracting mean value within a polygon for a raster stack

Tags: r, extract, raster

I have a set of rasters, which I would like to iterate over to extract the average value within the polygon for each raster. However, it's taking FOREVER. Can I create a raster brick from the stack to help with the processing time? Any other suggestions? I have 69 rasters... but I could cut it down to 14 if I really needed to.

```
iterate_raster <- function(grids_location, shp_location, func){
        #list files (in this case raster TIFFs)
        grids <- list.files(grids_location, pattern = "*.tif$")
        #read-in the polygon shapefile
        shp <- readShapePoly(shp_location)
        #create a raster stack
        st <- paste0(grids_location, "/")
        s <- stack(paste0(st, grids))
        ex <- extract(s, shp, fun=func, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE)
        return(data.frame(ex))
}

df <- iterate_raster(dep, spsh, mean)
```